How to enable docker remote api on macos sonoma via docker desktop?
I am having trouble setting up the Docker Remote API. I updated my daemon.json file with the following content:
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": false,
  "hosts": [
    "unix:///var/run/docker.sock",
    "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
  ]
}

After making these changes, Docker stopped working.
Can anyone help me identify what might be wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you!

The line that says tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 would introduce a major security hole.  Even on a MacOS host, it would allow anyone who can reach your machine over the network unrestricted read-write access to your home directory and whatever other directories you've given access in the Desktop UI.  You should never enable this option.
